# How to update text outside the addOnSuccessListener, after calling firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I want to assign the textview (with id "check"), with the size of the document list outside the addOnSuccessListener. I want to wait for the data to store inside the list then update the textview. As further, I want to filter list with nested spinners using onItemSelectedListner. And I don't want to do it inside the addOnSuccessListener.

**GalleryFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.demo.ui.gallery

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.demo.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var db = Firebase.firestore
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        var documents: MutableList<DocumentSnapshot> = mutableListOf()
        val textV = binding.check
        db.collection("product").document(id).collection("products")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                documents = result.documents
                textV.text = documents.size.toString()
            }

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

I tried to use Kotlin Coroutines but it is showing 0 inside the textview. How can I implement it?

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try {
                val result = db.collection("product")
                    .document(id)
                    .collection("products")
                    .get()
                    .await()
                documents.addAll(result.documents)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        textV.text = documents.size.toString()
```

This is giving 0 but when putting "textV.text = documents.size.toString()" inside the coroutine it is working fine. but I want it to work outside. Is There any way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to call the code from outside the listener, and what that means exactly? Do you mean you want to use a coroutine *instead* of using a success listener?

Comment: actually I need the all the products in my list and then I want to populate a spinner with all the "Machine Ids" and then after selecting that, I want to populate another spinner with all the "Model Ids" of the selected machine and accordingly show some graph. I want to populate the spinner outside the addOnsuccessListener.

Comment: As Tenfour04 asked, why not use a coroutine instead of a listener? Since you're using Kotlin, perhaps this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Comment: I edited my question and added it with using couroutine still it is not updating when putting this "textV.text = documents.size.toString()" outside the coroutine.

Comment: If you put the code outside the coroutine, it gets called before the coroutine has had a chance to run. If you want something to happen after the code in your coroutine, you have to do it inside the coroutine. The same is true with listeners.

Comment: oh, that means there is no possible ways to do that which I want, right?